# Resolving .net namespace conflicts

Tags: .net, f#, elmish

I'm using Giraffe and trying to integrate Elmish.Bridge. I get the following error:

`error FS0892: This declaration opens the module 'Elmish.Bridge.Giraffe', which is marked as 'RequireQualifiedAccess'. Adjust your code to use qualified references to the elements of the module instead, e.g. 'List.map' instead of 'map'. This change will ensure that your code is robust as new constructs are added to libraries.`

if I open the modules in the following order:

```
open Elmish.Bridge
open Giraffe
```

but if I swap the order then the error goes away.

```
open Giraffe
open Elmish.Bridge
```

Can someone please explain why this happens and how best to resolve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a naming conflict.

When you `open Elmish.Bridge`, this brings into scope the module `Elmish.Bridge.Giraffe`, and it becomes addressable by the name `Giraffe`. This is exactly what is supposed to happen when you open a module: all its content becomes "in scope".

The problem is that this conflicts with another module named `Giraffe`, coming from a different library.

When such naming conflict arises, F# gives preference to names from the most recently opened modules. Therefore, when you write `open Giraffe`, the compiler takes it to mean `open Elmish.Bridge.Giraffe`. And since that module requires qualified access (i.e. cannot be `open`ed), the compiler issues the relevant error.

When you put `open Giraffe` *before* `open Elmish.Bridge`, the compiler takes it to mean the module `Giraffe`, not `Elmish.Bridge.Giraffe`, because the latter is not yet in scope at that point. The global module `Giraffe` can be opened, so you get no error.

Besides changing the order of `open` lines, you can work around the conflict by explicitly specifying that you mean the "global" module `Giraffe`, not `Elmish.Bridge.Giraffe`, by using prefix `global.`, like this:

```
open Elmish.Bridge
open global.Giraffe
```